# How to register DbContextPool using Autofac?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, autofac

Microsoft's DI has `AddDbContextPool` but how to do it with `Autofac`?

Comment: won't it work adding `AddDbContextPool` in `ConfigureServices` method rather than in `ConfigureContainer`?

Comment: This won't work for console apps (not `asp.net core`) unless you have these 2 methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I guess, the standard workaround for cases like "*How to register something that exists in Microsoft's DI (logging, DbContext, etc.)?*" is using `ServiceCollection` and then calling `Populate` method.

My realization for `DbContextPool`:

```cs
public static void RegisterDbContextPool<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> options) where T : DbContext {
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddDbContextPool<T>(options);
    builder.Populate(serviceCollection);
}
```

[Docs](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/netcore.html)